# Instantiating similar webpages with different content

Tags: php, content-management-system

To begin, I'm sorry if the title is misleading. I find it hard to put it into words.

My question is regarding websites that have a lot of pages that are structurally identical, but the content is different.

Take Facebook as an example. Every person's profile is a "/profile.php" of some sort, but depending on whose profile you're viewing, the content is different.

It seems to me like there is one single .php-file for a profile, which loads content based on a profile ID in the database.

**So, the question:**
Certain types of CMS, like Drupal, do this. You create a node, and it has some content. You create another node of the same type, with different content, but it certainly doesn't create a brand new .php-file on your server for every single node, right? What's the process here? Can I program this using PHP?

I'm very much a beginner at PHP, but I'd very much like to learn how to achieve this practically.

Also, before any sarcastic "just use Drupal" comments arise, keep in mind that I do use that already, but again, I want to see if I can learn how to do this myself.

Comment: CMS like Drupal and Wordpress use templates .. the type of file you are taking about will also be a template file for like profiles .. you can have a system where you have users, and you can display each user information on profile.php by getting id of user .. what facebook does is it gets the id of current user from session .. or through url query strings .. also its not necessary that profile.php served by facebook is actually a real 'profile.php' file .. it can also be a template served by their application engine ..

Comment: This is a very broad topic. Can you give details on a specific use case you are struggling with? You may want to check out [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) or [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)

Comment: @neelsg - To narrow it somewhat, my short-term use case involves multiple (even hundreds of) pages that consist of a title, an embedded YouTube video, and a plain text description. I'd like to make these using a simple form, and then submitting that to create the page, each with its own URL based on the title.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this either on the server side using PHP or client side using JavaScript:

**Server side using PHP:**

If you navigate to a url like this: `http://example.com/p.php/someParameter`, it will actually go to `p.php`, but the entire uri is available at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, so you can strip ot the `someParameter` part and serve content dynamically. This would look something like:

```
<?php
$title = '';
$content = '';
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$slash = strrpos($uri, '/');
$parameter = substr($uri, $slash + 1, strlen($uri) - $slash);

// Update the title and content based on the parameter

?><html>
    <body>
        <h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
        <div><?php echo $content; ?></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Client side using JavaScript**

If you are happy to have the `#` in your path, there are various JS libraries that can make this quite easy as well. I use [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) and [Sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org/). For a tutorial on how to do that, check out [the knockout tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=webmail).